# Python - Grab a value from an output

Tags: python, output, paramiko

I am running a python script with paramiko module from my .send and .recv
I have this output

```
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 10 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 20 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 21 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 23 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 25 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 26 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 27 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 430 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 550 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 660 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 800 match address XXXXXXXXXXX
```

I need to grab the numerical value after OUTSIDEMAP (10, 20, 21, etc.). I have tried split method however the number of lines displayed can change anytime so I don' t have fix list value position.

Any idea?

Below the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko
import time

# Variables
host = xxxxxx = 'xxxxxx'

# Create instance of SSHClient object
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Automatically add untrusted hosts
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
# Automatically add untrusted hosts
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# initiate SSH connection
ssh.connect('xxxxxx', port=22, username='xxxxx', password='xxxxx', look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
print "SSH COnnection established with %s" % host

# Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
ssh_conn = ssh.invoke_shell()
print "Interactive SSH session established"

print "Give the name of the 3PPartner\n"
partner = raw_input('>')

# Commands prompted
ssh_conn.send('\n')
ssh_conn.send('enable\n')
time.sleep(.5)
ssh_conn.send('xxxxxxxn')
time.sleep(.5)
ssh_conn.send("terminal pager 0\n")
time.sleep(.5)
ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i ' + str(partner) + '\n')
time.sleep(1)
output = ssh_conn.recv(65535)

# Edit output
c_map = output.split(' ')
print c_map[25]
print c_map[31]
print c_map[37]


# Close session
ssh.close()
print 'Logged out of device %s' %host
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid regex?

Comment: Forget about that. Happy to go with regex as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it always the field after `OUTSIDEMAP`? If so, your idea with split() might work like this:

```
output = "crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 23 match address XXXXXXXXXXX"
outputList = output.split(" ")

index = outputList.index("OUTSIDEMAP")

if index > -1:
    numValue = outputList[index+1]
    print(numValue)
```

Output:

```
23
```

EdIT:

If its one long string together, you could use:

```
output = "crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 10 match address XXXXXXXXXXX\
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 20 match address XXXXXXXXXXX\
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 21 match address XXXXXXXXXXX\
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 23 match address XXXXXXXXXXX"


outputList = output.split(" ")
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(outputList) if x == "OUTSIDEMAP"]

print([outputList[x+1] for x in indices])
```

Output:

```
['10', '20', '21', '23']
```

Enumerate forms a list tuples of an index and a value. Like `[(0,"crypto"),(1, "map)...]` , the list comprehension fills a list with `i` if the value of `x` is `OUTSIDEMAP` so you get a list with indices for the occurance of `OUTSIDEMAP`. Then add 1 to it to get the field after, which contains the number you are looking for.

Alternatively with regex:

```
print(re.findall("OUTSIDEMAP (\d+) match",output))
```

Output:

```
['10', '20', '21', '23']
```

Comment: It partially works. It prints just the first value when I should have 11

federico@federico:~/github $ sudo python IPSEC_config_attributes.py
SSH COnnection established with 10.42.19.58
Interactive SSH session established
Give the name of the 3PPartner

>XXXXXX
10
Logged out of device x.x.x.x

Comment: Yeap! It works! You are the man! Now, I just need to understand what that piece of code means :D

Comment: @Federi added a small explanation